# Angular 8 - Protecting Admin Routes, Not able to get Uid from Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use angular 8, Firebase 6.6.2 & rxjs 6.4.0. Since i'm using rxjs latest version, i used switchMap inside the pipe. But i got the below error in the response.

> Argument of type '(user: User) => AngularFireObject<AppUser>' is not
> assignable to parameter of type '(value: User, index: number) =>
> ObservableInput<any>'.
>
> Type 'AngularFireObject<AppUser>' is not assignable to type
> 'ObservableInput<any>'.
>
> Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type
> 'AngularFireObject<AppUser>' but required in type 'Iterable<any>'.

Here is my code:

**user.service.ts**

```
get(uid: string): AngularFireObject<AppUser> {
    return this.db.object('/users/' + uid);
}
```

**app-user.ts**

```
export interface AppUser {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
}
```

**admin-auth.service.ts**

```
export class AdminAuthService implements CanActivate {

constructor(private auth: AuthService, private userService: UserService) { }

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.auth.user$
        .pipe(switchMap(user=> {
        return this.userService.get(user.uid);
    }));
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
export class AuthService {
  user$: Observable<firebase.User>;
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.user$ = afAuth.authState;
   }

  gLogin() {
    const returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl') || '/';
    localStorage.setItem('returnUrl', returnUrl);

    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  gLogout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

**Database:**

[image]

Comment: Could you show code of `AuthService.user$`?

Comment: @StepUp -  I have updated.

Comment: is it full code?

Comment: @StepUp - I have updated my full code.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting user in your `auth.service.ts`:

```
export class AuthService {
    user$: Observable<firebase.User>;

    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private userService: UserService) {
        this.user$ = afAuth.authState;
    }

    // The code omitted for the brevity

    public getappUser(): Observable<AppUser> {
      return this.user$
         .pipe(
              switchMap(user => {          
                  if (user) { 
                       return this.userService.get(user.uid).valueChanges(); 
                  }
                  return of(null);
              }));
    }      
}
```

In addition, you need to rename `admin-auth.service.ts` to `admin-auth-guard.service.ts`:

```
import { tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class AdminAuthGuard implements CanActivate {


  constructor(private auth: AuthService,
              private userService: UserService) { }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.getappUser()
      .pipe(
          tap(val => console.log(`BEFORE MAP: ${val}`)),
          map(x => x.isAdmin)
      );
  }
}
```

And then you can protect your routes using `AdminAuthGuard`:

```
import { AdminAuthGuard } from '...';

RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroesComponent,
    canActivate: [AdminAuthGuard]
  }
])
```

Comment: I followed the same but i get this error in admin auth guard. **Property 'isAdmin' does not exist on type 'Observable<AppUser>'.**

Comment: @Pkprabu it looks like there is no such property `isAdmin` in Firebase database. You should create this property in database.

Comment: I have updated my database also. isAdmin is database.

Comment: @Pkprabu could you write the following code snippet `tap()` method in `canActivate()` method? I've updated my code how you can do it. And show please, what you got.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save only the admin route, just read the users who are logged in, If logged in user is the admin then isAdmin is true then return true or false based on that.

**admin-auth.service.ts**

```
canActivate() {
    return this.auth.user$.pipe(map(user => {
      if (user.isAdmin) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }));
```

Comment: Its not working. i get this error. **Type 'Observable<unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'AngularFireObject<AppUser>': query, valueChanges, snapshotChanges, update, and 2 more**.

Comment: in admin auth service you are returning Observable of boolean value whereas you are returning Observable of AppUser from user service to canActive function, but canActive function returns Observable of boolean, I updated solution check that once

Comment: Now i get this error. **Type 'Observable<AppUser>' is missing the following properties from type 'AngularFireObject<AppUser>': query, valueChanges, snapshotChanges, update, and 2 more.**

Comment: If you want secure admin routes, read the logged-in user and check the user is admin or not, I updated code according to that

Comment: Now i get this error. **Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<User>'.** I think we need to use pipe operator to map

Comment: I added pipe and make sure you added rxjs library or else install https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs

Answer (score 0):

What must canActivate return? An `Observable`, right?

What do we return? an `AngularFireObject` which is not an Observable.

So, in **user.service.ts** file, Use `valueChanges()` method which will return an `Observable`.

```
get(uid: string): Observable<AppUser> {
  return this.db.object<AppUser>('/users/' + uid).valueChanges();
}
```

And in **admin-auth-guard.service.ts** file,

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.afService.user$.pipe(
    switchMap(({uid}) => this.userService.get(uid)),
    map(user => user.isAdmin)
  );
}
```

**To understand better:**
https://forum.codewithmosh.com/d/1210-oshop-protecting-admin-routes-not-able-to-get-uid-from-firebase/20

Answer (score 0):

After working for 3 months finally i figure this out problem is with rxjs its very hard to understand and also i am disappointed with mosh he should update his course.

Enough talking this what worked for me.

1. my bs-navbar code

(a) bs-navbar.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppUser } from 'src/app/models/app-user';
import { AuthService } from '../../servicese/auth.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'bs-navbar',
  templateUrl: './bs-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bs-navbar.component.css']
})
export class BsNavbarComponent {
  
  appUser: AppUser | undefined;

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {
    auth.getAppUser$().subscribe(appUser => this.appUser = appUser)}

  ngOnInit() {
   
  logout(){
    this.auth.logout();
  }
}
```

(b) bs-navbar.html

```html
<div class="level" (scroll)="scrolling($event)"  [ngClass]="{'level-trans': scroll}">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top p-md-3">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand nav-link" routerLink="/">VegShop</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"id="navbarNav">
        <div class="mx-auto"></div>
        <ul  class="navbar-nav text">       
        <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-md-0 text" (scroll)="scrolling($event)"  [ngClass]="{'text-trans': scroll}">  
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/shopping-cart">Shopping cart</a>
          </li>
          <ng-template #anonymousUser>
            <li class="nav-item ">
              <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
            </li>
          </ng-template>
          <div class="nav-dropdownleft">
            <li ngbDropdown *ngIf="appUser else anonymousUser" class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a ngbDropdownToggle class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
             {{ appUser.name}}
              </a>
               <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                 <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/my-orders">My Orders</a>
                 <ng-container *ngIf="appUser.isAdmin">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/admin-orders">Manage Orders</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/admin-products">Manage Products</a>
                 </ng-container>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="logout()">Log out</a>
               </div>
            </li> 
          </div>      
      </ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

2. user.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  save(user: firebase.User) {
    this.db.object('/user/' + user.uid).update({
      name: user.displayName,
      email: user.email,
    });
  }

  get(uid: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.db.object('/user/' + uid).valueChanges();
  }

  // AngularFireObject<AppUser>

  // Observable<any>

}
```

3. auth.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AppUser } from '../models/app-user';
import { switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  user$: Observable<firebase.User | any>;

  //making observable of type any because .pipe() is not applicable to null

  constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {
    this.user$ = afAuth.authState;
  }

  login() {
    let returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl') || '/';
    localStorage.setItem('returnUrl', returnUrl);
    return this.AuthLogin(new GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  async AuthLogin(provider: firebase.auth.AuthProvider) {
    try {
      const result = await this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(provider);
      console.log(result, 'You have been successfully logged in!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  logout() {
    this.afAuth.signOut();
  }

  getAppUser$(): Observable<AppUser> {
    return this.user$.pipe(
      switchMap((user) => {
        if (user) {
          return this.userService.get(user.uid);
        }
        return of(null);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

4. admin-guard.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import {map, tap} from "rxjs/operators";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private userService: UserService) { }
  

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean>{
    return this.auth.getAppUser$().pipe(
      map(x => x.isAdmin)
    )}
}
```

Note:- If you change isAdmin property to false and it still shows links then don't forget to hit enter after changing to false in database

Also import statements plays huge role if import map observable etc from wrong directory it won't show any error but your app will not work.